# Are there downsides in wrapping a functional component in a class?

Tags: reactjs, preact

Below I have a "functional" component wrapped in a arbitrary class simply to organize the code rather then including operations before the return within the functional component, I'm thinking about organizing the component in a class. This is conceptually different from a class component.

```
/** @jsx h */
import { h } from "preact";

class $NumberInput {

  constructor (
    public value: number,
    public onChange: (value: number) => void) {}
  

  get proceessValue () {
    if (this.value === 1) return 2
    return this.value
  }

  render() {
    return <input type="number" value={this.proceessValue}/>;
  }
}

function NumberInput (props: { value: number, onChange: (value: number) => void }) {
  const Number = new $NumberInput(props.value, props.onChange).render;
  return <Number />
}
```

Are there any downsides rendering a component from a class in this way, when it comes to optimizing the dom tree? Would I want to `memo` this `const Number` call?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? A new instance of the class will be recreated at every new render, so every internal state of the class will be lost, which is kind of the whole point of classes. I guess you could maybe memo it, but again, why complicate things so much? Function components and modules are perfectly fine for code organization.